# Datepicker bootstrap en Python (Django)

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, jquery-ui-timepicker-addon

La implementación básica del Datepicker de Bootstrap funciona correctamente, lo que no funciona es el `datesDisabled` (desactivar fechas):

Mi forms.py:

```
class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    dateTimeOptions = {
    'format': 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    'autoclose': True,
    'startDate': datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y"),
    'datesDisabled': ['20/02/2017']
    }
    
    model = Reserva
    fields = ['fecha_entrada','fecha_salida']   
    widgets = {
        'fecha_entrada': DateWidget(attrs={'id':"start",'readonly':'readonly','class':'datepicker'}, usel10n = True, bootstrap_version=3, options = dateTimeOptions),
        'fecha_salida': DateWidget(attrs={'id':"end",'readonly':'readonly','class':'datepicker'}, usel10n = True, bootstrap_version=3, options = dateTimeOptions)
    }
```

Básicamente lo que hace este form es insertar un `script` por cada input tal que así:

```js
$("#start").datetimepicker({
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
  autoclose: true,
  startDate: '28/01/2017',
  startView: 2,
  minView: 2,
  language: 'es'
}).find('input').addClass("form-control");
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>



<input id="start" class="datepicker">
```

Este `script` es lo que requiere `Bootstrap` en el `.html` para su funcionamiento. El problema surge cuando le inserto el `datesDisabled: ['20/02/2017']` por ejemplo, tal y como pone la [documentación de Bootstrap](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#datesdisabled) y parece ser que le da igual, ningún tipo de error, simplemente no lo lee. Tengo última versión de Bootstrap, JavaScript y jQuery.

Comment: Podrías mostrar como lo estás insertando en el template por favor?

Comment: Se implementa insertando {{ bookForm }} en el HTML siendo bookForm = BookForm().
Utilizo esta implementación: https://github.com/asaglimbeni/django-datetime-widget ya que te genera automáticamente el código JavaScript. Si conoces algun otro método no me importaría utilizarlo, aunque sea a pelo, solo quiero poder desactivar determinadas fechas en el datepicker.

Answer (score 1):

A ver si planteandolo de esta otra forma lo hacemos funcionar:

```js
var disableddates = ["20-02-2017", "21-02-2017"];

function DisableSpecificDates(date) {
  var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date);
  return [disableddates.indexOf(string) == -1];
}

$("#start").datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: DisableSpecificDates
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>



<input id="start" class="datepicker">
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda

Answer (score 0):

No veo el datesDisabled en el código de Javascript, pero a priori la diferencia que veo está en que faltarían los dos puntos.

```js
$("#start").datetimepicker({
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
  autoclose: true,
  startDate: '28/01/2017',
  datesDisabled: ['20/02/2017'],
  startView: 2,
  minView: 2,
  language: 'es'
}).find('input').addClass("form-control");
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>



<input id="start" class="datepicker">
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda

Comment: Disculpa, lo escribí mal en el post, lo tengo tal y como tu indicas: datesDisabled: ['20/02/2017'],

No funciona :(